# PASSWORD ON TABLE

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

i am using oracle 11g and i want to set password on table or other objects in oracle so is it possible to set password on table  in oracle?

Comment: is it possible or not ? someone tell me

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of the Password is to protect data then, consider 
Roles / User Privileges on db object (table) or you can even encrypt / decrypt data